# Array filter working like a marktplace filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I need make the filter work like a markeplace filter, if a set the brand, i just will see the brand related itens, if i set a status for this brand, only the brand with my preset status.

***Real Example:***

```
partners = [
0:{
ano: "2022"
badge_status: "badge-success"
data_venda: "01/07/2022"
item_venda: "OATMEAL STOUT - Mark The Shadow"
mes: "JULHO"
parceiro: "BASTARDS"
qtd_itens: 1
status: "CONCLUIDA" // **true**
valor_pago: 1
},
1:{
ano: "2022"
badge_status: "badge-danger"
data_venda: "04/07/2022"
item_venda: "IPA - Hector 5 Rounds"
mes: "JULHO"
parceiro: "BASTARDS"
qtd_itens: 1
status: "Houve algum erro no pagamento" // **false**
valor_pago: 4
},
2:{
ano: "2022"
badge_status: "badge-success"
data_venda: "04/07/2022"
item_venda: "IPA - Hector 5 Rounds"
mes: "JULHO"
parceiro: "BASTARDS"
qtd_itens: 3
status: "CONCLUIDA" // **true**
valor_pago: 3
}
]
```

This is my actually array of DB, i'm need filter the 'item_venda' and/or 'status'.
Each item_venda selected, need return the array like the indexed image below

```
 this.filtered2 = function(filtering){
      //  console.clear()
      let filterInput = this.search
      let filters = [...this.search].filter(input=> input.value).map(input => ({
        filter: input.name,
        value: input.value
      }))
      console.log('Itens a procurar', filters)
       return filtrada.filter(produto => {
        console.log('PRODUTO', produto)
        return filters.every(filter =>{
          console.log("Filter", filter)
          return produto[filter.filter] == filter.value
        })
      })
```

*My first filter will be select the year, month and the partner:*

*So, in my new array, i will get only the products of the selected partner, the sell month and year*

*Now becames the problem, i want filter again, to see only on my list the selected products, and if a set a status(sold/not_sold), return only the filtered products, with the selected status*
Will work like a marketplace array, when whe select a brand, a price range , lenght...

Actually with the @nem0z tip, with the first item_venda selected, return the filtered array, but when select the second... item_venda, return only [].

***THIS.SEARCH will receive value for each select on HTML***

[Image of table only with item_venda filter][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E9sn.png

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] an not your full code. People here help dozens of people a day, we can't focus on a full length code to answer you.

Comment: @temp_user, thks for the help, i edited the code to a better visualization

Answer (score 0):

Note : The code is fully costumizable and you can add / remove the filters you (don't) need ;)

Let's say you have an `array` of `object` representing products, you can filter it using html selects with this code :

JS :

```
    const products = [
    {
        productName: 'product 1',
        partner: 'partner 1',
        status: true,
    },
    {
        productName: 'product 2',
        partner: 'partner 1',
        status: true,
    },
    {
        productName: 'product 1',
        partner: 'partner 2',
        status: false,
    },
];

let filterProducts = function(products) {
    let filterInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.filter');

    let filters = [...filterInputs].filter(input => input.value).map(input => ({filter: input.name, value: input.value}));

    return products.filter(product => {
        return filters.every(filter => {
            return product[filter.filter] == filter.value;
        });
    });
}

document.querySelector('#searchBtn').addEventListener('click', e => {
    let result = filterProducts(products);
    console.log(result);
});
```

HTML :

```
    <select name="productName" class="filter">
    <option value="">-----</option>
    <option value="product 1">product 1</option>
    <option value="product 2">product 2</option>
</select>

<select name="partner" class="filter">
    <option value="">-----</option>
    <option value="partner 1">partner 1</option>
    <option value="partner 2">partner 2</option>
</select>

<select name="status" class="filter">
    <option value="">-----</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
```

Comment: This almost worked with me, but i can't use a array to filter, like select, product1, product 2 and list just then.

Comment: Can we explain more clearly (edit your post with exemple maybe) ? What do you use then ?

Comment: i edited with my actually running TS code, if you can help me i'm grateful